# How to connect with AVT guppy camera in c#?

Tags: c#, camera, connect, avr, firewire

Camera is running on FireWire bus, AVT smartView is running, but I can´t find any c# code example, how to work with camera. I tried Emgu CV, but it doesn´t work. Is there someone who was working with AVT camera? Any suggestion how to start? I´m just beginner.

Answer (score 1):

AVT suggests to use the [**VIMBA SDK**](http://www.alliedvisiontec.com/apac/products/software/vimba-sdk.html)

After finishing the installation you will find the `VimbaNET.dll` in the installed folder like this:

> C:\Programme\Allied Vision Technologies\AVTVimba_1.2\VimbaNET\Bin\Win32

Use it as reference in your Project.
It is an .NET 2.0 Assembly if you use a higher Framework you need change the app.config File like this:

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework ,Version=v4.0" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Example to list all available AVT Cameras:

```
string strName;
Vimba sys = new Vimba();
CameraCollection cameras = null;

try {
    sys.Startup();
    cameras = sys.Cameras;

    Console.WriteLine("Cameras found: " + cameras.Count);
    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach(Camera camera in cameras) {
        try {
            strName = camera.Name;
        } catch (VimbaException ve) {
            strName = ve.Message;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("/// Camera Name: " + strName);
    }
} finally {
    sys.Shutdown();
}
```

For more examples View the Documentation in the

> C:\Programme\Allied Vision Technologies\AVTVimba_1.2\VimbaNET\Documentation Folder.

Comment: It seems you know more about this topic. Can you please explain it here in this post? It will be helpful for future visitors :)

Comment: Tried my best to give more detailed information. Hope it helps future visitors better that way.